# SSIS data flow to update source table rows after copying to destination

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a simple data flow that copies a subset of data from a source table on an internal database to a table on web-facing database.

If there is a problem, the error is outputted to an errors table.

That's all fine.

In the source table there is a bit column for `SSIS_TRANSFERRED` that I wish to set to 1 when the copy process completes. However, I'm unsure how to approach this.

My instinct is to craft an SQL Statement that runs against each Unique ID for every row successfully transferred as part of that package - is there a simple approach to this (i.e. as part of the data flow) or do I need to create a new Control Flow with OLE DB Command that queries the web-facing table and marks the corresponding internal rows as 'transferred' accordingly?

[image]

Comment: For those who try to make a change to the data source input and then put that in a new destination output table without leaving the DFT, you can do this in a Script Component of the DFT, see [How do I create and fill a temporary table from a data source by means of a C# DataTable without ever leaving the SSIS Data Flow Task?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/338129/212659). The code is for a temporary table, but you can also put a normal table instead. You can then fill the table and change its column with SQL and still pass the input further down the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep all the components within the current Data Flow Task, then you could add a Multicast within this Data Flow Task, with one output to the destination and the other output to an OLE DB Command that updates the source records based on the rows transferred to the destination.  However the Multicast transformation is a synchronous transformation, thus the records will go to both outputs simultaneously and this could lead to blocking or deadlock issues.  A simpler approach may be to just add an Execute SQL Task after the Control Flow Task that updates the source table based on the transferred records from the destination table.

[image]

For the update, you'll want to do a set-based update, such as the SQL statement below.  To only perform this update based on rows transferred within that package execution, a Multicast could used in the Data Flow Task to output only the unique IDs to a staging table, and then update the source based on the matching IDs in the staging table in the subsequent Execute SQL Task.  Just make sure to add a step to truncate the staging table in the beginning of the package to clear data from the prior execution.

```
UPDATE SRC
SET SRC.SSIS_TRANSFERRED = 1
FROM dbo.SourceTable SRC
INNER JOIN dbo.DestinationTable DEST 
ON SRC.ID = DEST.ID
```

Comment: Yes. This will do the trick! I will implement this approach.

Comment: The question is meant as asking for a workaround, it seems, since this answer got accepted and since the question allows Control Flow answers as well. Still, it should be made clear that this does not answer the question header. Your answer is about the Control Flow tool "Execute SQL Task". If someone wanted to stay inside the DFT, this would not help. Then, you could check [How do I create and fill a temporary table from a data source by means of a C# DataTable without ever leaving the SSIS Data Flow Task?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/338129/212659).

Answer (score 3):

With T-SQL there's an `output inserted` [clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) which would be really helpful in this scenario.

I'm not aware of a way to do that with SSIS, so your alternate approach of using a second data flow after your first (you can connect the second data flow to the first so your dependency will be honored), querying the web database, and updating the internal one as appropriate will work as long as your workload can tolerate the additional latency involved in waiting to update the `SSIS_TRANSFERRED` column.

Comment: Useful information. Thanks for confirming a second data flow approach.

Answer (score 3):

As @mark Iannucci says, the OUTPUT clause will be your friend here.

The following query demonstrates the approach.

```
-- Just setup junk
DECLARE
    @SRC TABLE
(
    SSIS_TRANSFERRED bit
,   col2 int
)
;

INSERT INTO
    @SRC
(
    SSIS_TRANSFERRED
,   col2
)
SELECT TOP 100
    0 AS SSIS_TRANSFERRED
,   CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS int) AS col2
FROM
    sys.all_columns AS AC;


-- This is what you will use in your Source component
-- Copy this logic into your component
UPDATE SRC
SET SRC.SSIS_TRANSFERRED = 1
OUTPUT Deleted.*
FROM @SRC SRC
WHERE SRC.SSIS_TRANSFERRED = 0;
```

How this works, is that it will update your source data. That's an atomic operation - it does or doesn't. If it updates a row, it is emitted to the SSIS buffers and will flow to your destination. If something bad happens, the transaction blows up and no data is added to the buffer.

Note that I use the `Deleted` virtual table with the original value of 0 for SSIS_TRANSFERRED. Had I selected `Inserted`, then I'd have rows with a 1 value. What the expected behaviour for your target is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to leave the Data Flow Task back for the Control Flow, you can do the UPDATE statements of the other answers also:

- in an [OLE DB Command Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/ole-db-command-transformation?view=sql-server-ver16)

  > The OLE DB Command transformation runs an SQL statement for each row in a data flow. For example, you can run an SQL statement that inserts, updates, or deletes rows in a database table.
- or in a Script Component in C#.

And if there are problems with locked tables or a problem from changing the data source table that your data flow runs on, check whether you might make a second (temporary?) table and insert only the ID and the bit column. Update that temporary table during the SSIS run.

At the end of the transfer, update the data source table with the values of the second table. By doing this in one go, you might get a better speed (if changes in the source table trigger an update of the data flow at least, which I do not know). What you could also do is to add the new bit column of the temporary table to the passed input dataset with a lookup component or with C# again.

See [How do I create and fill a temporary table from a data source by means of a C# DataTable without ever leaving the SSIS Data Flow Task?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/338129/212659) for an example how you could create and fill a temporary table in the same DFT, without leaving it for the Control Flow. The code is for a temporary table, but you can also put a normal table instead. You can then fill the (temporary) table and change its column with SQL and still pass the full source table input further down the stream, and:

- map the new bit column from the (temporary) table or
- update the data source in one go.

But also without a temporary table, you might find a way with C# Script Components:

- add an output column "bit column 2" to the Script Component with the new entries that you pass down the stream of the DFT, and at the end when the data source is no longer needed, update the data source in one go in a Script Component.